# How to use <Redirect /> if you have <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> in between <Route />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My goal is to redirect undefined path to `/account`

Working example:

```
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/account" component={AccountComponent} />
        <Route exact path="/members" component={MembersComponent} />
        <Route exact path="/members/:username" component={MemberComponent} />
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={LogoutService} />
        <Redirect to="/account" />
      </Switch>
```

The problem is when I tried to hide some route based on "Do the user has access to this route":

```
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/account" component={AccountComponent} />
        {hasAuthority("member:info", credentials.authorities) && (
          <>
            <Route exact path="/members" component={MembersComponent} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/members/:username"
              component={MemberComponent}
            />
          </>
        )}

        <Route exact path="/logout" component={LogoutService} />
        <Redirect to="/account" />
      </Switch>
```

My expected result is: When I go to `/undefinedroute`, `React Router` should redirect me to `/account`.

My actual result is: When I go to `/undefinedroute`, `React Router` did not redirect.

The solution I can think of right now is to either use `<Route render={} />` or do not use <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>:

```
        {hasAuthority("member:info", credentials.authorities) && (
          <Route exact path="/members" component={MembersComponent} />
        )}
        {hasAuthority("member:info", credentials.authorities) && (
          <Route exact path="/members/:username" component={MemberComponent} />
        )}
```

But I found this to do "unnecessary" method's call.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose redirecting to a `/` home page

`App.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

// You can use the last <Route> in a <Switch> as a kind of
// "fallback" route, to catch 404 errors.
//
// There are a few useful things to note about this example:
//
// - A <Switch> renders the first child <Route> that matches
// - A <Redirect> may be used to redirect old URLs to new ones
// - A <Route path="*> always matches

export default function NoMatchExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/old-match">Old Match, to be redirected</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-match">Will Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/will-not-match">Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/also/will/not/match">Also Will Not Match</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/old-match">
            <Redirect to="/will-match" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/will-match">
            <WillMatch />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*">
            <NoMatch />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h3>Home</h3>;
}

function WillMatch() {
  return <h3>Matched!</h3>;
}

function NoMatch() {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will prevent defining new Route below the `{isAuthenticated ? ... : ...}`. I am starting to believe this is `React Router`'s bug.

Comment: Code has been update
Ref: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match